# $.getJSON interpreted differently by IE - Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, getjson

I am trying to do the classic category -> subcategory chained dropdowns (where selecting something in category, populates the subcategory).

The code I have works in all browsers except IE (naturally).

Here is the JS code I am using:

```
$("body select#category").data_binding({
    child: "select#company_subcategory_id",
    url: "subcategories",
});

   [ . . . ]

    data_binding: function(options) 
    {
            $(this).change(function()
            {
                    $.getJSON("/"+ options.url +"/",
                             { id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, 
                              function(j)
                              { 
                                    for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) 
                                    {
                                       options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">';
                                       options += j[i].optionDisplay;
                                       options += '</option>';
                                    }

                                    $(child).html(options);
                              });
            });
   }
```

Subcategories controller

```
class SubcategoriesController < ApplicationController
  layout 'application'

  def index
       @subcategories = Subcategory.find_all_by_category_id(params[:id])
       respond_to do |format|
           format.js {render :json => @subcategories.collect {|sc| {:optionValue => sc.id,
                                                           :optionDisplay => sc.name} }.to_json }
          end
  end

  def show  
      @subcategory = Subcategory.category_permalink_like(params[:category]).
                                             permalink_like(params[:subcategory]).first
      @with_banner = @subcategory.companies.active.with_banner
      @without_banner = @subcategory.companies.active.without_banner
   end
end
```

I'm tailing the development.log file and when I use any browser except IE the log shows

```
Processing SubcategoriesController#show (for 192.168.1.70 at 2010-08-26 01:49:06) [GET]
Parameters: {"id"=>"4", "_"=>"1282805337516", "show_type"=>"available_banners"}
```

but when I use IE I get

```
Processing SubcategoriesController#create (for 192.168.1.70 at 2010-08-26 01:50:09) [POST]
Parameters: {"ajax"=>"true", "authenticity_token"=>"Eg2XAvSSHg/v12cKjTPt+HkKWhxdGW3s5n6lm9jHu2A=", "id"=>"6"}
```

There is no defined create action, so it crashes.

I have no idea why this is interpreted differently :/

Any suggestions?

Thanks!!

Comment: What does SubcategoriesController#create look like?

Comment: there is no SubcategoriesController#create

It is not supposed to be called at all :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a ridiculous fix for the problem, but I am at my wits end and this seems to work.

I modified the subcategories controller like so:

```
class SubcategoriesController < ApplicationController
  layout 'application'

  def index
   @subcategories = Subcategory.find_all_by_category_id(params[:id])
   respond_to do |format|
       format.js {render :json => @subcategories.collect {|sc| {:optionValue => sc.id,
                                                       :optionDisplay => sc.name} }.to_json }
      end
  end

  def show  
      @subcategory = Subcategory.category_permalink_like(params[:category]).
                                         permalink_like(params[:subcategory]).first
      @with_banner = @subcategory.companies.active.with_banner
      @without_banner = @subcategory.companies.active.without_banner
   end

   #this is the added method
   def create
      index
   end
end
```

for some reason, IE keeps trying to call the `create` method in the subcategories controller where all the other browsers play nice and call the `index` method

I really don't know why this is happening, so this hack will have to do for now :(

I've simplified the code I posed above so its easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I recall debugging an issue very similar to this recently.  If I recall correctly, it has to do with the mime type & dataType passed to jquery.  Look at using get, or getScript instead.